# How to get current user in another file while working on postman and node.js

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I have this code for login. How do I use the current user's information from this code to another file using postman and node.js?

```
exports.loginUser = (req,res, next) => {
User.find({email: req.body.email})
.exec() 
.then(user => {
    if(user.length < 1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Auth failed'
        });
    }
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err ,result) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Auth failed'
            }); 
        }
        
        if (result) {
            const token = jwt.sign({
                email: user[0].email,
                userId: user[0]._id
            }, 
            process.env.JWT_KEY ,
            {
                //options
                expiresIn: "1h"
                
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tell exactly what you want, what you said is confusing, but If you mean how to pass the logged in user to the next middleware, you gotto assign the `user` to `req`

```js
exports.loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {
        const user = await User.find({ email: req.body.email }).exec()
        if (user.length < 1) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Auth failed'
            });
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(401).json({
                            message: 'Auth failed'
                        });
                    }

                    if (result) {
                        const token = jwt.sign({
                                email: user[0].email,
                                userId: user[0]._id
                            },
                            process.env.JWT_KEY, {
                                //options
                                expiresIn: "1h"

                            });
                            req.user = user[0];
                            return next();
                        }
                    })
            }
```

Then in the next middleware you have access to logged in user, using `req.user`.

UPDATE:

To implement the functionality that you want, according to what you described in the comment:

Before anything import these packages:

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const { promisify } = require("util");
```

First you implement a route that checks for credentials and sends back a signed `jwt`:

```js
exports.login = CatchAsync(async(req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if (!email || !password) {
        return next(new Error("Please provide email and password"));
    }

    const user = await UserModel.findOne({email});

    if (!user) {
        return next(new Error("There is no user with that email"));
    }

    if(!(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
        // actually the pass is not correct but for security reasons we don't say that
        return next(new Error("Email or password is not correct");
    }

    // pass the user id to jwt so later can identify user
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, 'yourJwtSecret', {
        expiresIn: '90d',
    });

    // httpOnly prevents access to token in client's browser, so it is safe
    const cookieOptions = {
        expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        ),
        httpOnly: true,
    };

    res.cookie("jwt", token, cookieOptions);

    res.status(200).json({
         status: 'success',
         message: 'logged in successfully'
    });

});
```

Then for every route that needs to check for logged In user, use this middleware:

```js
exports.isLoggedIn = CatchAsync(async(req, res, next) => {
    // Check if there is a token
    // if no token was provided it means user is not logged in
    let token;
    if (req.cookies.jwt) {
        token = req.cookies.jwt;
    } else {
        return next();
    }

    // Verify token
    // decoded now has access to id of user
    let decoded;
    try {
        decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, 'yourJwtSecret');
    } catch (err) {
        // if token was modified or expired or not valid
        return next();
    }

    // get the user
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({
        _id: decoded.id
    });

    // access granted, user is logged in
    req.user = user; // you can access the logged in user in the next middleware
    res.locals.user = user; // you can access the logged in user in template engines
    next();
});
```

If the user is not logged in, `req.user` won't be assigned. therefore in next middlewares if `req.user` was `undefined` you know user is not logged in.

for more info [jwt](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) docs.

If you have never taken any NodeJs course, I'd recommend [this course](https://www.udemy.com/course/nodejs-express-mongodb-bootcamp/)

Comment: Okay, what I am trying to do is an app like freelancer and I am doing the employer side. I have this users controller (where the login function is) Then I have jobs controller ( to post a job). In jobs controller I want to check the logged user's bank account before he posts a job. I got confused because there is no session to hold the current logged user. Thanks but how do I access this req.user in another file.

Comment: @H.adugna The only way to pass any data to the next middleware is to attach it to `req` param and in the next middleware you have access to `req` and therefore have access to `req.user` like: `console.log(req.user)`

Comment: @H.adugna But the implementation is wrong. You implement a login route for user to login and if the credintials are currect, you send back a `jwt`. afterwards whenever user wants to make a request, the user should provide the `jwt`. using that `jwt` you can confirm if the user is logged in or he is what he says he is. This proccess is a little long to tell in a comment, therefore I will complete my answer according to your needs, please wait for it.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply thanks a lot. But can you tell me how to call IsLogged function in another controller

Comment: @H.adugna You just add it to the middleware stack, for example: `router.post("/post", isLoggedIn, createPost);`. now if `req.user` is `undefined` in `createPost` function, it indicates the user is not logged in and vice versa.  for more info [Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Oh, Okay. Thnks alot

Comment: @H.adugna If this answered your question, then you can mark this answer as correct.